# AngularJS modal with google map API

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-maps

I have my main page which contains a list of location. Below the table, there is a button wich should open a pop-up containing a form to add a new location.

This pop-up should contains a google map which will show the entered address.

Click on "Create new location"

```
<button ng-click="CreateLocationPopup();" class="btn btn-xs btn-mercedes">@Labels.NewLocation</button>
```

Call the function

```
angular.module('App').controller("LocationController", ['$scope', '$modal',
function($scope, $modal) {

    $scope.CreateLocationPopup = function () {
        $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'CreateLocation.html',
            size: 'lg'
        });
    };
}
]);
```

Which open this (placed in the main page with the location table)

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="CreateLocation.html">
     <event-location></event-location>
</script>
```

The `event-location` directive only call a fonction in my MVC controller which will only call a `PartialView`.

In my creation pop-up I have different fields and the image preview

```
<div id="img-canvas">
    <img id="img-preview" src="@Url.Content(pictureUrl)" alt="location image preview" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;" accept="image/*" />
</div>


<div id="map-canvas" style="height: 400px; width: 600px; margin-top: 60px; margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto;"></div>
```

The problem is that I need to call 2 javascript function when the page is rendered but calling them in my partial view does not work (Javascript is not firing)

```
 initializeLocationMap("map-canvas");
 previewImage("ImageBrowse", "img-preview");
```

All the fiels are well displayed except for the google map image

Comment: You have a mistake in `[$scope'`, you miss one quote

Comment: Just a fail when copy/past - oops

Comment: So where are you execute and define this `initializeLocationMap` function

Comment: That's the problem. If I put it in the main page I got an error because the img-canvas and img-preview are not yet rendered

Comment: Can you create a snippet or bin with whole code? It's not that hard..

Comment: I actually solved the problem myself. Anyway thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by myself. This was the first time I used `directive`.

I added `link` to my `event-location` directive

```
    link : function() {
        initializeLocationMap("map-canvas");
        previewImage("ImageBrowse", "img-preview");
    }
```